# Can Windows/Linux instances share an ebs volume?

Tags: windows, linux, filesystems

I have windows and linux amis. When windows and linux instances are started from these amis, can these two share same ebs volume? 
I did the following, 
created a new volume, 
attached this volume to running LINUX instance, 
put a test content into this volume. 
Now i want this test content to be available to a new WINDOWS instance. What should i do?

Comment: Just attach the volume to the new Windows instance?

Comment: attaching simply didnot work since we need to mount. But, during mounting in windows, its asking for formatting. If I format, I lose all the content. So, Is thr a way to attach and mount without formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a single volume attached to more than one instance at a time, but you could move it between instances.  If you want it to be read by Linux and Windows, it would need to be formatted with a file system that both operating systems understand.

Comment: fat32, ntfs. A quick Google shows that drivers do exist to mount ext3 on windows. But performance and stability might well be issues if the drivers haven't had much production level testing/use.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct that you cannot directly mount the same EBS volume on more than one instance at the same time but it might be sufficient for your requirement to indirectly mount it (at the same time) using a network file system protocol.

For example you could use [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System_%28protocol%29). From an architecture perspective you would need at least one instance to act as an NFS server which other instances (including the server) could mount from as clients.

Taking this a step further you could do away with EBS altogether and use [S3 Fuse](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/) to mount an S3 Bucket as a shared drive. Client software exists for both Linux and Windows.

Every abstraction adds more overheads so you will need to judge the performance against your requirements.

Comment: I thought I should go with detaching the ebs volume from linux after putting the test content. I want to attach this volume back to windows instance. can you suggest how do I attach and mount this volume to WINDOWS instance without formatting it again so that I dont lose the test content? Thanks!

Comment: You haven't said what filesystem you are using, find that out and google 'mount <filesystem> windows'.